# Missing required parameters for [Route: users.update] [URI: users/{user}]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want to update the user authenticator update information by a using jQuery ajax, but it gives me error `Missing required parameters for [Route: users.update] [URI: users / {user}]. (View: D: \ wamp \ www \ aswakt \ resources \ views \ users \ edit.blade.php)`, and I apologize because I am a beginner.

hi, i want to update the user authenticator update information by a using jQuery ajax, but it gives me error `Missing required parameters for [Route: users.update] [URI: users / {user}]. (View: D: \ wamp \ www \ aswakt \ resources \ views \ users \ edit.blade.php)`, and I apologize because I am a beginner.

**edit.blade.php**

```
<table class="table ">
 <tbody>
  <tr data-name='{{ $users->name }}'>
    <th scope="row"> name </th>
    <td>{{ $users->name }}</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-name='{{ $users->email }}'>
    <th scope="row"> email </th>
    <td>{{ $users->email }}</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-edit', function(e) {
              let $btn = $(this).hide();
              let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
              let name = $tr.data('name');
              $tr.children("td:eq(0)").html(`<input name="edit_name" value="${name}">`);
              $tr.children("td:eq(1)").prepend("<button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-update'>Update</button><button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-cancel'>Cancel</button>")
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-update', function(e) {
              let $btn = $(this);
              let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
              let name = $tr.find('[name="edit_name"]').val();
              $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "{{ route('users.update') }}",
              data: {
                     'name':name, 
                     'id':id,
                     "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                    },
              success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $tr.data({ name });
                $tr.children("td:eq(0)").text(name);
                $tr.find(".btn-edit").show();
                $tr.find(".btn-update, .btn-cancel").remove();
              },
              error: function(){
                  console.log('error');
              },
              });
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-cancel', function(e) {
              let $btn = $(this);
              let $tr = $btn.closest('tr');
              $tr.children("td:eq(0)").text(() => $tr.data('name'));
              $tr.find(".btn-edit").show();
              $tr.find(".btn-update, .btn-cancel").remove();
            });
    </script>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user=User::find($id);
        $user->id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user->update($request->all());
        session()->flash('success', 'user updated successfully !!');
       return redirect('users'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your AJAX URL to: `{{ route('users.update', $users->id) }}`